# How do I auto-fill the area above a line graph with solid color?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made a chart with 2 line graphs.  The red line is the high temperature of the day and the blue line is the low temperature of the day.  Temps is the Dataframe, High is the high temp, Low is the low temp.

```
Temps = Temps.set_index('Date')
Temps['High'].plot()
Temps['Low'].plot()
```

Here's the resulting chart:

[image]

How do I automatically fill-in the area above the red line with solid red color?  And then automatically fill-in the area below the blue line with solid blue color?  Is it possible with MatPlotLib to make it something like the chart below (excuse the crude Paint job)?

[image]

Comment: I suspect we use "plt.fill_between", but what happens when there's no top line to fill-in "between" (as in the case of the red-colored part in Chart 2)?

Comment: If it helped, please accept it as the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible with matplotlib using `fill_between`.

```
# library
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
# Create data
x=range(1,6)
y=[1,4,6,8,4]
z = [8-i for i in y]

# Area plot below line
plt.fill_between(x, y, color='g')
plt.show()

# Area plot above line
plt.fill_between(x, y, max(y), color='r')
plt.show()
```

---

[image]

---

**Complete Solution:**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({"Datum": ['1/2/2018',
                             '1/3/2018',
                             '1/4/2018',
                             '1/5/2018',
                             '1/6/2018',
                             '1/7/2018',
                             '1/8/2018',
                             '1/9/2018'],
                   "Menge": [19.5, 19.,19.5,19.5,21,19.5,20,23]})
# sns.lineplot(x="Datum", y="Menge", data=df)
df['Datum'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datum'])
df.set_index('Datum', inplace=True)
df['Menge2'] = df.Menge+12
df['Menge'].plot()
df['Menge2'].plot()

# Area plot below line
plt.fill_between(df.index, df.Menge, color='g')
# plt.show()

# Area plot above line
plt.fill_between(df.index, df.Menge2, max(df.Menge2), color='r')
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you Pygirl.  I chose your solution because it didn't require me to trash my existing code and to rewrite everything.  As a new learner, I am trying to understand how to modify what I already coded to achieve the result I want.  With the other solutions, it didn't use my existing DataFrame, or the method of plot that I had already used, and I was therefore more confused by their solution.  Thanks for extending my existing code (in your "Complete Solution") rather than having me  redo everything.   It was much easier for me to understand/grasp.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I will approach it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 20
low = 10 * np.random.rand(n, 1)
high = low + 5

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(range(n), low, color='g')
ax.plot(range(n), high, color='r')
ax.fill_between(range(n), low.squeeze(), ax.get_ylim()[0], color='g')
ax.fill_between(range(n), ax.get_ylim()[1], high.squeeze(),  color='r')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [fill_between](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html) function from matplotlib. Here's a snipper if you want to use matplotlib with a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Temps = pd.DataFrame()
Temps['Date'] = pd.date_range(start='20-08-2019', end='20-09-2019', freq='D')
Temps['High'] = np.random.random(32)+2
Temps['Low'] = np.random.random(32)+1
Temps = Temps.set_index('Date')


plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
plt.fill_between(Temps.index, Temps['High'], 4, facecolor='red')
plt.fill_between(Temps.index, Temps['Low'], 0, facecolor='blue')
```

[image]